# Special meaning of Enter: expect -re "Press \[Enter\] to continue:" does not work

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

I'm a bit puzzled by the regular expression processing in `expect` script. My spawned executable will send back several messages with text like `Press [Enter] to continue:`. I thought that the processing should as following:

```
spawn /tmp/install.run --prefix /opt --mode text

expect {
    timeout { send_user "\nFailure to initiate license view\n"; exit 1 }
    eof { send_user "\nGeneral error\n"; exit 1 }
    -re "Press \[Enter\] to continue:" { send "\r" }
}
```

However, the script refuses to recognize the text coming back. It only works if use this regular expression: `"Press .Enter\] to continue:"`.

Is there something special about `Enter` keyword in the expect script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you've used `""` quotes instead of `{}` braces, TCL is processing the backslashes before the string gets to the regex engine, producing a string with no backslashes in it. That means the `\[Enter\]` is being treated as a character class `[Enter]`.

Use braces for regexes:

```
    -re {Press \[Enter\] to continue:} { send "\r" }
```